# Parameter-specific usage of "SupportsShouldProcess

Tags: powershell

Please have a look at the code snippet bellow. I am making use of the `SupportsShouldProcess` parameter within the `CmdletBinding` decorator, which provides me with two additional "builtin" functions namely `-whatif` and `-confirm`

However, having to use the parameter `SupportsShouldProcess` on top provides the ability to all functions/parameters that are going to be used by the user. For the example below, my `ParameterSetname="Help"` also gets the ability.

So the question is: How can I provide `-whatif` and `-confirm` only to specific parameters/functions?

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Help", SupportsShouldProcess)]
Param(
    [parameter(ParameterSetName="Help")]
    [switch]$Help,

    # Client Management
    [parameter(ParameterSetName="MoveAdComputerObjects", Position=0)]
    [switch]$MoveAdComputerObjects,

    # Additional parameters 
    [parameter(ParameterSetName="MoveAdComputerObjects", Mandatory)]
    [ValidatePattern("foobar")]
    [string]$Src,

    [parameter(ParameterSetName="MoveAdComputerObjects", Mandatory)]
    [ValidatePattern("foobar")]
    [string]$Dst
)

Function Help
{
    Write-Host 
    Get-Command -Syntax $MyInvocation.ScriptName
}

Function MoveAdComputerObjects 
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param(
        [ValidatePattern("foobar")]
        [string]$Src,

        [ValidatePattern("foobar")]
        [string]$Dst
    )

    # Do something useful
    Write-Host $Src, $Dst
}

switch($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
{
    "Help"                  { Help }
    "MoveAdComputerObjects" { MoveAdComputerObjects -Src $Src -Dst $Dst } 
}
```

Comment: `if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess) ...` can control the behaviour.